# throw an alert if a key is pressed inside a textbox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do something like this, but it is not working. Is there a way of doing it differently?

```
if($("#user_password").keypress()){
    alert("hello");
}
```

user_password is the id of a textbox on my login screen.

i have canceled the event for all textboxes when you push enter, but i want to allow them to press enter only in this password field on the login page. so my complete code is:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
if($("#user_password").keypress()){
    alert("hello");
}
if(e.which == 13 && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") return false;
});
```

Comment: you are using id then why would you need to cancel for others. id is unique it can applied only to one element in page. check my answer if that is the thing you are looking for. my answer would work on when you press enter in user_password field

Comment: you can do a fiddle that would be more helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set an event handler, `if` statements aren't relevant here:

```
$("#user_password").keypress(function () {
  alert("hello");
});
```

If you want to find out which element triggered an event, look at the event's `target` property:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.target == $("#user_password")[0])
    alert("hello");

   if(e.which == 13 && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") return false;
});
```

Comment: i added a bit more code to my explanation of what i need.

Comment: is keyup not going to do job??

Comment: he is just saying if condition is not relevant @EhsanSajjad

Comment: well the problem is i dont know how to detect if a user has pressed enter in a specific textbox and allow them to do it, where everywhere else, it gets canceled

Comment: as the user who asked question used if on keypress. he just told in that scope.

Comment: yes I saw that but I am just confirming that keyup will do the same job or not?

Comment: yeah keyup is better @EhsanSajjad

Comment: the second block of code worked perfectly. thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#user_password").on("keyup", function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code  === 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter key in textbox with id user_password');
        }
    });
});
```